# How to disable read-write mode in Ubuntu Touch without a PC?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I've installed Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 7 2013 and enabled read-write mode just like the Ubuntu wiki says.

But now I've found there are many bugs in it so I decided to upgrade my system.

Here is the question: I don't have my Ubuntu PC here, so how can I disable read-write mode (probably using the terminal app or a Windows PC)?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Terminal app in your phone and enter:

```bash
sudo mount -o remount,ro /
```